# Having different application orientation for tablets and phones

Tags: android

I know I can specific application orientation (Portrait or Landscape) through manifest file.

My application will run on both tablets and phones. However, currently, I would like to have `Landscape` orientation for tablet application, and `Portrait` for phone application.

May I know, how I can achieve this, by only having to build a single APK file. Or, do I need 2 different APK files for tablets and phones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put this in onCreate method:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

sets the orientation to device default.